# Opening/saving encrypted zip file from iOS mail app

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, encryption, zip

I have a problem with opening an encrypted/protected by a password zip file from an e-mail in an iOS mail app.

I can enter the preview of the file, however it is a blank page with the file name only and the text: "zip archive", but the action button (the square with the arrow) does nothing.

I have WinZip app installed  on the device. 
Anyone knows the solution to this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Mail wont open zip files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235890/ios-mail-wont-open-zip-files)

Comment: Not a duplicate as the other question says noting about encryption